# MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED html5 audio woes

Tags: audio, html

I am working on an html5 audio player and everything is working fine when I server the .ogg file from the same host as the html page. When I put the ogg file in my cdn it fails and the error code is MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED

For example, this works fine

```
<audio src="/song.ogg" id="player">
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

But this fails with the above error code

```
<audio src="http://mycdn.com/song.ogg" id="player">
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

The headers for the audio file that fails look something like this (this is from a different ogg file which exhibits the same behavior)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: CacheFlyServe v26b
Date: Sat, 13 Feb 2010 21:10:48 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Connection: close
ETag: "c6ee7d86e808cc44bbd74a8db94a5aae"
X-CF1: fA.syd1:cf:cacheD.syd1-01
Content-Length: 2398477
Last-Modified: Sat, 13 Feb 2010 20:50:56 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Cache: MISS from deliveryD-syd1
```

Comment: I couldn't come up with an idea explaining this (you can see the possible reasons enumerated at http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html ). It would be easier if you stated what version of what browser you use, listed the headers or, better, even provided the testcase with real URLs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Content-Type=octet/stream header is the problem, although if I'm reading the spec correctly, it shouldn't be. Here's a testcase: http://mozilla.doslash.org/stuff/video-test/video.html

I [filed a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546129) in Mozilla's bugzilla about this. [edit] the response:

> We don't do any content sniffing to work out what the content is - we rely on
>   the correct mime type being provided. This is why application/octet-stream does
>   not play and way we return "" for canPlayType.

Comment: thanks, I think I was in need of sleep when I posted this. I could have sworn I looked at the Content-Type of the one that worked and that it was application/octet-stream. Looking at it now it's application/ogg

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the mime type you are serving the audio file with. It needs to be 'audio/ogg', 'application/ogg' or 'video/ogg' for Firefox to play it. Firefox doesn't do any form of 'content sniffing' to work out what format the file is in - it relies entirely on the mime type.