# Is it possible to bypass browser security rules allowing to open local resources?

Tags: html, windows, google-chrome, iis, browser

Each Win10 computer in our organization has mapped network drive H:. 
I'm developing intranet website and trying to implement function that on html button click it will open mapped drive H: (need to open by explorer.exe not the browser).

```
<button type="button"><a href="file://H:/" target="_explorer.exe">Open drive</a></button>
```

The problem is that browsers apply security rules not allowing to load local resources.

[image]

All our computers are connected to domain. Intranet website is hosted on our win2012r2 server by IIS. Mapped network drive file server is also connected to domain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open local file from browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430889/how-to-open-local-file-from-browser)

Comment: @EvertvdH. unfortunately no. In my understanding person is trying to open certain local file.