# Cannot open a local file from webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, protocols

I want to open files from webpage. For example when we try to download a torrent file it redirects us to utorrent app and it continues it work. I also want to open a local file somehow using OS software. Like a video file using pot player. Is there any possible solution for me ,like making a autorun in pc to run that . Anything it may be please help me.

I searched and found a solution to open a software using protocol, but in this way I cannot open a file in that software.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open local file from browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430889/how-to-open-local-file-from-browser)

Comment: *"it redirects us to utorrent app"* - That's because the installed application has configured the host to handle a certain protocol (e.g. `magnet://`).  This is controlled from that application's installation, not from the web page.  Replicating this behavior would involve the user installing your custom application (or browser plugin) on their machine first.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a specific file in a specific software would usually depend on passing some URL parameters to the protocol-URL of the app (e.g., opening a file in `VSCode` would use a URL like `vscode:///Users/me/file.html`, but this functionality would have to be explicitly handled by the app itself though, so the solution for each app would be different).

Otherwise, if the app doesn't support opening a specific file itself through a URL, you'd have to use some scripting software (e.g. AppleScript if you're on macOS) to dynamically click/open certain programs on a user's computer.

Answer (score 0):

the link acts as a magnet so your torrent application is opened maybe delete torrent for sometime till you finish the project, i know how to open image in local files in html but it will only be visible to you, you can do audio and video files also using `<source src="movie.mp4` and on next line `type="video/mp4">

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).